# UIScrollView scrolls slowly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have created `UIView` with Width = 3500.

Inside the view I draw a SoundWave using a `CAShapeLayer` with `UIBezierPath` that contains 70008 samples spaced each other 0.05 (70008*0.05=3500).

The lineWidth for the `UIBezierPath` is 0.10.

The content is read Only once using an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` width 140016256 Frame capacity.

When the `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is read 2000 values every 1 is "not read" (140016256/2000 = 70008)

The Content of the `UIView` is the contextSize for a `UIScrollView` so when the user drags into the scroll view, he can see the different parts of the SoundWave.

The problem is that when scrolling it takes a long time to perfom the scroll.

Here is the code:

```
func drawSoundWave(fromSample:Int64, toSample:Int64){
    // Drawing code
    print("\(logClassName): Drawing from = \(fromSample) to \(toSample)")

    if readFile != nil{

        let soundPath = UIBezierPath()
        soundPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        soundPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0 , y: middleY))

        let testTo = Int64(toSample)


        let sequence = stride(from: fromSample, to: testTo, by: 2000)



        var testIndex = 0
        for element in sequence {

            let newSample = CGFloat(readFile?.audioBuffer.floatChannelData?.pointee.advanced(by: Int(element)).pointee ?? 0)

            print("\(logClassName): newSample = \(newSample) -> TestIndex = \(testIndex) in Element = \(element)")

            /** Continuous View **/
            let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: soundPath.currentPoint.x + sampleSpace,
                                    y: middleY - (newSample * 100) - 1.0)

            soundPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
            soundPath.move(to: nextPoint)

            testIndex += 1
        }


        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        trackLayer.path = soundPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 0.10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    }

}
```

Is there something I can do different for optimising the code or I am using to many resources?

EDIT:

The `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is inside an struct called readFile.
The Function is not called in Draw method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I can do different for optimising the code or I am using to many resources?

The first thing you can do is to profile your code to find out where it's spending most of the time. Is the problem that you're reading samples from a file one at a time? Perhaps using a stride of 2000 causes most of the benefit of the file buffer to be lost, so that reading every 2000th sample from the file is more expensive than you realize? Or is it that you're creating a new bezier path or shape layer every time through? Maybe it's just that print statement for every sample that's taking time? **You can't really know how to speed up your code until you know where it's slow.**

Keep in mind that during scrolling, your draw method is going to be called repeatedly, and it should do as little real work as possible. If your code is recomputing data for the entire visible area when it only needs to draw the newly exposed data, that's an opportunity for a big speed increase. Drawing at lower resolution during scrolling and then redrawing at full resolution when scrolling has stopped can help. Keeping a low-resolution (in terms of samples) bezier path on hand instead of creating a new one all the time might help. But again: **measure first, improve second.**

One thing that jumps out is that you're drawing 70,000 data points into a view that's 3500 pixels wide. Twenty data points for every pixel of width is *far* more data than the user can discern even when the view isn't moving; when the user is scrolling, they're hardly seeing any of that data. Even if you have to look at that many samples to find the peaks and troughs of the wave, you surely don't need to add that many points to the path.

Comment: Trying to identify. The UIBezierPath is only drawn Once. I am gonna try to see if the resolution is too much

Comment: @ReimondHill The path is only drawn once each time your draw method is called, but the draw method will be called repeatedly as the user scrolls.

Comment: 1 every 2000 was too much. I ended up doing 1 every 4800 so a Second has 10 samples